# Important rails 3.2 concepts needed in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails: What are some concepts that are present in Rails 3 that will be changed or need to be dropped completely when I start with Rails 4(beta version is released)?

Also got to know that the usage of ActiveRecord observers, it has been extracted to a gem.  the new gem will be located at github.com,rails-observers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Release Notes (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html):

### Highlights

**Ruby 2.0 preferred; 1.9.3+ required**

This is pretty self-explanatory.

**Strong Parameters**

Allows you to specify permissible attributes for mass assignment from **the controller**.

Read more about it here: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/strong-parameters-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

**Turbolinks**

"Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head."

See the github page: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

**Russian Doll Caching**

It's a caching technique, which you can read more about here: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

### Major changes and deprecations

Features extracted into gems:

- [Hash-based & Dynamic finder methods](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders)
- [Mass assignment protection in Active Record models](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes)
- [ActiveRecord::SessionStore](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store)
- [Active Record Observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers)
- [Active Resource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource)
- [Action Caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching)
- [Page Caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching)
- [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails)
- [Performance tests](https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest)

If you use Rails default test framework, the directories have changes as follows:

- test/units          -> test/models
- test/units/helpers  -> test/helpers
- test/functional     -> test/controllers
- test/functional     -> test/mailers
- test/integration    -> test/acceptance

**Vendor Plugins**

Deprecated. Any plugins you might have in vendor/plugins will have to be installed as gems.

**Active Record**

The following methods are deprecated and will need to be rewritten as follows:

- `find_all_by_...` can be rewritten using `where(...)`.
- `find_last_by_...` can be rewritten using `where(...).last`.
- `scoped_by_...` can be rewritten using `where(...)`.
- `find_or_initialize_by_...` can be rewritten using `where(...).first_or_initialize`.
- `find_or_create_by_...` can be rewritten using `find_or_create_by(...)` or `where(...).first_or_create`.
- `find_or_create_by_...!` can be rewritten using `find_or_create_by!(...)` or `where(...).first_or_create!`.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan has a nice synopsis of whats new in Rails 4 here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4

Answer (score 1):

The resource I like most to see the differences (and to know how to upgrade) is the book and website from Andi Lindemann [Upgrading to Rails 4](http://www.upgradingtorails4.com/). He discusses some of the changes, and explains what to do to migrate.

Part of his book is the following summary (copied as plain text, the book of course includes the details):

- Upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or 2.0.0
- Upgrade bundler
- Check for gem incompatibilities using rails4_upgrade
- Upgrade Rails itself
- Add gems that have extracted functionality from Rails 3
- Upgrade plugins to gems or move code to lib/
- Tweak any routes that use match without :via => :verb
- Audit any chained uses of Relation#order, as new orders are now prepended rather than appended
- Decide whether graceful degredation of remote forms is important to your application and, if so, enable the option to embed authenticity tokens in forms
- Add any image assets in lib/ or vendor/ to the precompilation list

Some functionality from earlier versions of Rails has been deprecated: while
your application may continue to operate correctly, you will see warnings.
After you have addressed the concerns in the first checklist, consider
addressing deprecated features:

- Modernize Rails 2 finder syntax
- Modernize dynamic finders
- Change eager-evaluated scopes to use lambdas
- Audit any uses of Relation#all
- Address any uses of Relation#includes with conditions on the joined table
- Remove the whiny_nils setting from all environment configuration files
- Remove the auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds setting from all environment configuration files
- Add new thread-safety configuration options